# Handling 'Sequence has no elements' Exception

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, ado.net

I am updating a quantity in my cart, but it is throwing a Sequence has no elements' exception.

And I don't know what that even means. At first I thought that maybe there was a null value being passed somewhere, but that isn't the case, as I've checked that:

> Sequence contains no elements    Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence
>   contains no elements
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 35:                 var uid = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId; Line 36:
>   var newqty = Request.Form["Quantity"]; Line 37:
>   OModel.Cart c = (from item in database.Carts Line 38:
>   where item.UserId == uid && item.PartNumber == pnumber && item.OrderId
>   == oid Line 39:                                    select item).First();

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

`First()` is causing this if your select returns 0 rows. You either have to catch that exception, or use `FirstOrDefault()` which will return `null` in case of no elements.

Answer (score 18):

You are using LINQ's `First()` method, which [as per the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976) throws an `InvalidOperationException` if you are calling it on an empty collection.

If you expect the result of your query to be empty sometimes, you likely want to use `FirstOrDefault()`, which will return `null` if the collection is empty, instead of throwing an exception.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of `.First()` change it to `.FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 2):

Part of the answer to 'handle' the 'Sequence has no elements' Exception in **VB** is to test for empty

```
If Not (myMap Is Nothing) Then
' execute code
End if
```

Where MyMap is the sequence queried returning empty/null.  FYI

Answer (score 1):

The value is null, you have to check why...
 (in addition to the implementation of the solutions proposed here)

Check the hardware Connections.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue but I was not using First(), instead, I was using ToListAsync(). My issue was that I had not made the attributes in my entity class public. Making them public solved my issue.

Before :

```
string name {get; set;}
```

After :

```
public string name {get; set;}
```